# Excel macro output

Tags: vb.net, excel

The following code generates a sequential list of numbers beginning at zero within an Excel macro output. My question is: How do I tell the code not to display any of the items below zero?

```
SolidRight (PageSheet.Cells(3, 1))
For t = 1 To Columns_per_page
    PageSheet.Cells(3, (t * 2)).Value = ((NewPageNum - 1) * Columns_per_page) + t - 9
    If t Mod 2 = 0 Then
        SolidRight (PageSheet.Cells(3, (t * 2) + 4)) ' 1)) DM
    Else
        DotRight (PageSheet.Cells(3, (t * 2) + 4))  '  1)) DM
    End If
Next t
```

Comment: you have to show your functions also.